# Is there a way to configure git that it apply `--color-moved` option by default?

Tags: git, git-config

As of [Git 2.15, `git show` now supports](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) detection of moved lines with the `--color-moved` option. It works for moves across files.

Is there a way to configure git that it apply `--color-moved` option by default?

Answer (score 7):

The documentation of `git diff` should be checked. Run next command to colorize moved code:

```
git config --global diff.colorMoved default
```

Answer (score 4):

Note: with Git 2.19 (Q3 2018), the "`git diff --color-moved`" feature has further been tweaked.

See [commit 626c0b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/626c0b5d395196ddabcf9b9a430db385722689d4), [commit ca1f4ae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca1f4ae4dfade677647928d28728a0cad125981d) (18 Jul 2018), and [commit e2fe6ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e2fe6abc3b8cc78f8dd3dac938bcd63e918e647f), [commit b309571](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3095712f9d81572c3658d579e50db907b72f46d), [commit 51da15e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/51da15eb2301667c6ac01dd18851b7a424fbf2b1), [commit ee1df66](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee1df66f7cfd0f37bb0e235c4f7ef12bd09a8d2d), [commit 3783aad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3783aad4c8e08ed7905bada47dc7b5df94bfa74a), [commit 74cfa7b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/74cfa7bed96ea003e0a3ea20455096187c517b19), [commit 21c770b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21c770b63ea7ddcb6e52527d82089068b33eb9f3), [commit 25790be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25790be634afc3eb28a2ba8d0f6579aaab10bc27) (16 Jul 2018) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a81575a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a81575aa91a015535374bb5b1e0e6dc2a81c74ab), 02 Aug 2018)</sup>

First, the new default option is blocks, not zebra

> ### `diff.c`: add a **blocks** mode for moved code detection

> The new "`blocks`" mode provides a middle ground between plain and zebra.
> It is as intuitive (few colors) as plain, but still has the requirement for a minimum of lines/characters to count a block as moved.
>
> - With blocks, adjacent blocks cannot be told apart.
> - With zebra, the change between the two colors indicates that a new block was detected.

So remember this when using the [`git config --global diff.colorMoved default`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-diffcolorMoved) setting.
The **default mode** (see [`git diff` modes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---color-movedltmodegt)) will be blocks, no longer zebra.

---

Then a block comes with whitespace management:

> ### `diff.c`: add white space mode to move detection that allows indent changes

> The option of `--color-moved` has proven to be useful as observed on the
> mailing list. However when refactoring sometimes the indentation changes,
> for example when partitioning a functions into smaller helper functions
> the code usually mostly moved around except for a decrease in indentation.
>
> To just review the moved code ignoring the change in indentation, a mode
> to ignore spaces in the move detection as implemented in a previous patch
> would be enough.  However the whole move coloring as motivated in commit
> [2e2d5ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e2d5ac184de8facde4e14cec8b4e2a154480ed8) (diff.c: color moved lines differently, 2017-06-30, Git v2.15.0), brought
> up the notion of the reviewer being able to trust the move of a "block".
>
> As there are languages such as python, which depend on proper relative
> indentation for the control flow of the program, ignoring any white space
> change in a block would not uphold the promises of [2e2d5ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e2d5ac184de8facde4e14cec8b4e2a154480ed8) that allows
> reviewers to pay less attention to the inside of a block, as inside
> the reviewer wants to assume the same program flow.
>
> This new mode of white space ignorance will take this into account and will
> only allow the same white space changes per line in each block. This patch
> even allows only for the same change at the beginning of the lines.
>
> As this is a white space mode, it is made exclusive to other white space
> modes in the move detection.
>
> This patch brings some challenges, related to the detection of blocks.
> We need a wide net to catch the possible moved lines, but then need to
> narrow down to check if the blocks are still intact. Consider this
> example (ignoring block sizes):
>
> ```
> - A
> - B
> - C
> +    A
> +    B
> +    C
> ```
>
> At the beginning of a block when checking if there is a counterpart
> for `A`, we have to ignore all space changes. However at the following
> lines we have to check if the indent change stayed the same.
>
> Checking if the indentation change did stay the same, is done by computing
> the indentation change by the difference in line length, and then assume
> the change is only in the beginning of the longer line, the common tail
> is the same. That is why the test contains lines like:
>
> ```
> - <TAB> A
> ...
> + A <TAB>
> ...
> ```
>
> As the first line starting a block is caught using a compare function that
> ignores white spaces unlike the rest of the block, where the white space
> delta is taken into account for the comparison, we also have to think about
> the following situation:
>
> ```
> - A
> - B
> -   A
> -   B
> +    A
> +    B
> +      A
> +      B
> ```
>
> When checking if the first `A` (both in the `+` and `-` lines) is a start of
> a block, we have to check all '`A`' and record all the white space deltas
> such that we can find the example above to be just one block that is
> indented.

---

And it is tweaked (again) in Git 2.21 (Q1 2019)

See [commit 0cd51e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cd51e9d05e65608126c30fbb65a0cdd197cd570), [commit 21536d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21536d077f4b7b8a249f1fc894dafc38f06cef0f), [commit 7a4252c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a4252c4df49fe07bf91dbb5be2c6012f6a65329), [commit b0a2ba4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0a2ba47761fa7bffb5a33e5a76f85da50a00ba5), [commit 2034b47](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2034b473e1316d206c39be67dcb3f71fa93c06f5), [commit 10acc5f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10acc5f750789fcfd38e43810f2c372b134a807c), [commit b73bcba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b73bcbac4a9d8c76ccdda0f0ac4b122b8e96e4b7), [commit 748aa1a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/748aa1aa34a316b8f26a3664f3fdcd273e1c5c39), [commit fbafb7c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbafb7c682272e039e7aacbf8c0ef8de3c0eb157) (23 Nov 2018) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 15b07cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15b07cba0b60f0fc5dea0be0d68a355a8161476d), 29 Jan 2019)</sup>

> Even if you have set this as default, you can turn it off temporarily with `--no-color-moved`
>
> Turn off move detection.
> This can be used to override configuration settings.
> It is the same as `--color-moved=no`.

And:

> ### `diff --color-moved-ws`: handle blank lines

> When using `--color-moved-ws=allow-indentation-change`, allow lines with the same indentation change to be grouped across blank lines.
> For now this only works if the blank lines have been moved as well, not for
> blocks that have just had their indentation changed.
>
> This completes the changes to the implementation of `--color-moved=allow-indentation-change`.
> Running:
>
> ```
> git diff --color-moved=allow-indentation-change v2.18.0 v2.19.0
> ```
>
> now takes 5.0s.
> This is a saving of 41% from 8.5s for the optimized version of the previous implementation and 66% from the original which took 14.6s.

---

And with Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), "`diff --color-moved`" is faster because it stops clearing potential moved blocks, amongst other optimizations.

See [commit 72962e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/72962e8b3c3ea3a631166876b4668718103be4fe), [commit b4a5c5c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b4a5c5c419009c26935536fa7039ad5073acb237), [commit 25e6190](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25e61909e95ffd376787ce0ecc5dd6cf7d3f0e78), [commit eec7f53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eec7f53b3150dcc54ea0f4441587724be65c105d), [commit 0e488f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e488f173257e5ab766267ac5a5c4c9f3f1ce343), [commit ff046a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff046a0066f55cb730ced3f8eb54d508dcd3a4c7), [commit 08fba10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08fba1076faf0b2c0bfeda628c84ac15efd27cfb), [commit 52d14e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/52d14e166d7360b17f74ae169a83e5e642892bdb), [commit 76e32d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76e32d619323c89e44ebfcfdb9d44766937b17dc), [commit eb89352](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb893525041a53b968a46000ed5cb66ffc725853), [commit eb31545](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb315457f65e1d6b77cde3933b6a175e649fb34b), [commit 0990658](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0990658bf85a0763ffd628b1dd57a33c27b25450), [commit 7dfe427](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7dfe427107a3765456e9fa33c56da29fea24cf0f), [commit bea084b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bea084ba41ffcaf5896522e48d67682b6a45b04c), [commit f73613a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f73613ac33aad6f08aa1bc07e596202f19e760d1) (09 Dec 2021) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2b755b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b755b337134aac9b1386e2d216cf734e1e229d2), 05 Jan 2022)</sup>

> ### [`diff --color-moved`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eec7f53b3150dcc54ea0f4441587724be65c105d): stop clearing potential moved blocks
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> `moved_block_clear()` was introduced in [74d156f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/74d156f4a1b1d563b422127ee347eaa348973a0c) ("diff --color-moved-ws: fix double free crash", 2018-10-04, Git v2.20.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2916cfe851444c730a533e5045b46cc661f5d9c3) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4df23f7927d8d00e666a3c8d1b3375f1dc8a3c1)) to free the memory that was allocated when initializing a potential moved block.
> However since [21536d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21536d077f4b7b8a249f1fc894dafc38f06cef0f) ("diff --color-moved-ws: modify allow-indentation-change", 2018-11-23, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15b07cba0b60f0fc5dea0be0d68a355a8161476d) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a)) initializing a potential moved block no longer allocates any memory.
> Up until the last commit we were relying on `moved_block_clear()` to set the `match` pointer to `NULL` when a block stopped matching, but since that commit we do not clear a moved block that does not match so it does not make sense to clear them elsewhere.